# summarizing data in R (pivot) with disctinct sum

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, reshape2

I am trying to summarize my data table similar to what we do in pivot table in Excel, but here I want to use count distinct and  sum distinct

```
df <- data.frame(order_date =c("15-07-2019","15-07-2019","15-07-2019",
                                 "15-07-2019","15-07-2019","15-07-2019",
                                 "15-07-2019","15-07-2019"), 
                   hour = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2), 
                   Country = c("KSA","KSA","UAE","UAE",
                               "UAE","KSA","KW","KW"), 
                   Order_language = c("English","English","English",
                                      "English","English","English",
                                      "English","English"),
                   order_no = c(400130191,400130191,500239645,500239645,
                                500239645,400158425,600009114,600009114), 
                   item_number = c(1365453,1365454,1365463,1365464,1365465,
                                   1365457,1365537,1365538),
                   item_total = c(100,120,100,50,145,214,1,4) , 
                   order_total = c(234,234,359,359,359,234,5.142,5.142))
```

I want to summarize the dataframe in Pivot table format (looks something like this)

```
summary <- data.frame(hour =c(1,2),
                        Total_order = c(3,1), 
                        Total_Item =c(6,2),
                        gross_Sales = c(827,10.4),
                        KSA_order = c(2,0),
                        KSA_item = c(3,0) ,
                        KSA_gross_sales = c(468,0))
```

Here,

> ```
> Total_order = distinct_count(order_no) for that hour
> Total_Item = distinct_count(item_number) for that hour
> gross_Sales = distinct_sum_per_order(order_total) for that hour
> KSA_order = distinct_count(order_no) for that hour for KSA country filter
> KSA_item = distinct_count(item_number) for that hour for KSA country filter
> KSA_gross_sales = distinct_sum_per_order(order_total)  for that hour for KSA country filter
> ```

I tried to use group by and summarize, but I am stuck at calculation of gross_sales, as have to take distinct sum of order_total

```
summary <- df %>% 
            group_by(hour) %>% 
            summarise(KSA_order_cnt = n_distinct(order_no[Country == "KSA"]), 
                      KSA_item_cnt = n_distinct(item_number[Country == "KSA"]),
                      KSA_net_sales = sum(order_total[Country == "KSA"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be we need

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(hour) %>%
   summarise(Total_order = n_distinct(order_no),
             Total_Item = n(),
             gross_Sales = sum(unique(order_total)), 
             KSA_order = n_distinct(order_no[Country == 'KSA']), 
             KSA_item = sum(Country == 'KSA'),
             KSA_gross_sales = sum(unique(order_total[Country == 'KSA'])))
```

Comment: But the problem will occur when i have 2 orders with same order value. I have specifically pointed out this in the dataframe, for example order number  400158425 has same order value as 400130191  and hence will show 234 as the output instead of  468.